# Why do LED bulbs in my three-bulb fixture remain on unless one is incandescent?

Tags: led, replacement, bulb

I have a three bulb light fitting that worked fine with 40 watt golf ball bulbs. On removing the bulbs and inserting the first 5.5 watt led the bulb illuminated while the fitting was turned off. This only happened in the one bulb holder the other two worked fine. The fitting now has 2 leds and 1 40 watt bulb and is working fine, any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Is there a dimmer on the circuit?

Comment: No dimmer but are switched 2 way and work fine off both switches?

Comment: Do either of the switches have an internal light that comes on when switched off?